# Snakemake database update rule

Tags: python, snakemake

I am wondering how to design a database update (amrfinder db) and query with snakemake.

rule update_amrfinder, updates the database and creates a checkpoint file called update_finished.txt

rule amrfinder_query starts the database query after the update has been performed.

Is there a way to work without the checkpoint file update_finished ?

```
rule update_amrfinder:
    output:
        db="update_finished.txt",
    conda:
        "../envs/amrfinder.yaml"
    shell:
        " amrfinder -u   1> {output.db}"

rule amrfinder_query:
    input:
        fasta="{sample}.fasta",
        db="update_finished.txt",
    output:
        "{sample}_amrfinder.tsv",
    conda:
        "../envs/amrfinder.yaml"
    shell:
        " amrfinder -n {input.fasta} 1> {output}"
```